# JPA Left Join IS NULL condition not working

Tags: java, jpa, join, eclipselink, jpql

I have User and Employee tables on MySQL, and there is employeeId as foreign key in User table.

Now I need to get Employees who do not have User.

I write this SQL in MySQL Workbench, this works exactly how I want:

```
SELECT * FROM HUMANRESOURCE.EMPLOYEE E LEFT JOIN AUTHORIZE.USER U 
                                       ON U.EMPLOYEEOBJID = E.OBJID  
                                       WHERE U.EMPLOYEEOBJID is NULL;
```

But when I try to implement this SQL as JPA query, it returns nothing. Here is JPA Query:

```
Query query = em.createQuery("SELECT e FROM Employee e LEFT JOIN User u 
                                        WHERE u.employee.objid = e.objid 
                                        AND u.employee IS NULL");
```

And here is truely working JPA Query that I use for getting Employees who have user:

```
Query query = em.createQuery("SELECT e FROM Employee e INNER JOIN User u 
                                       WHERE u.employee.objid = e.objid");
```

What am I doing wrong here?

**Update for entity classes:**

*Base.java*

```
package com.kadir.entity;

import java.math.BigInteger;
import java.sql.Timestamp;
import java.util.Date;

import javax.persistence.Cacheable;
import javax.persistence.Column;
import javax.persistence.GeneratedValue;
import javax.persistence.GenerationType;
import javax.persistence.Id;
import javax.persistence.MappedSuperclass;
import javax.persistence.Version;


@Cacheable
@MappedSuperclass
public abstract class Base {
    @Id
    @GeneratedValue(strategy = GenerationType.IDENTITY)
    @Column(name = "OBJID")
    private BigInteger objid;

    @Column(name = "CREATEDBY")
    private String createdby;

    @Column(name = "CREATEDDATE")
    private Timestamp createddate;

    @Version
    @Column(name = "ROWVERSION")
    private Integer rowversion;

    @Column(name = "UPDATEDBY")
    private String updatedby;

    @Column(name = "UPDATEDDATE")
    private Timestamp updateddate;

    @Column(name = "ARCHIVED", columnDefinition = "int default 0")
    private int archived;

    public BigInteger getObjid() {
        return this.objid;
    }

    public void setObjid(BigInteger objid) {
        this.objid = objid;
    }

    public String getCreatedby() {
        return this.createdby;
    }

    public void setCreatedby(String createdby) {
        this.createdby = createdby;
    }

    public Date getCreateddate() {
        return this.createddate;
    }

    public void setCreateddate(Timestamp createddate) {
        this.createddate = createddate;
    }

    public Integer getRowversion() {
        return this.rowversion;
    }

    public void setRowversion(Integer rowversion) {
        this.rowversion = rowversion;
    }

    public String getUpdatedby() {
        return this.updatedby;
    }

    public void setUpdatedby(String updatedby) {
        this.updatedby = updatedby;
    }

    public Timestamp getUpdateddate() {
        return this.updateddate;
    }

    public void setUpdateddate(Timestamp updateddate) {
        this.updateddate = updateddate;
    }

    public int getArchived() {
        return archived;
    }

    public void setArchived(int archived) {
        this.archived = archived;
    }
}
```

*Employee.java*

```
package com.kadir.entity.humanresource;

import com.kadir.entity.corporation.Company;
import com.kadir.entity.Base;

import java.io.Serializable;

import javax.persistence.*;


/**
 * The persistent class for the EMPLOYEE database table.
 * 
 */
@Cacheable
@Entity
@Table(name = "EMPLOYEE", schema = "HUMANRESOURCE")
@NamedQuery(name = "Employee.findAll", query = "SELECT e FROM Employee e")
public class Employee extends Base implements Serializable {
    private static final long serialVersionUID = 1L;

    @ManyToOne
    @JoinColumn(name = "COMPANYOBJID")
    private Company company;

    @Column(name = "FIRSTNAME")
    private String firstname;

    @Column(name = "GENDER")
    private int gender;

    @Column(name = "EMAIL")
    private String email;

    @Column(name = "PHONE")
    private String phone;

    @Column(name = "LASTNAME")
    private String lastname;

    public Employee() {
    }

    public Company getCompany() {
        return this.company;
    }

    public void setCompany(Company company) {
        this.company = company;
    }

    public String getFirstname() {
        return this.firstname;
    }

    public void setFirstname(String firstname) {
        this.firstname = firstname;
    }

    public int getGender() {
        return this.gender;
    }

    public void setGender(int gender) {
        this.gender = gender;
    }

    public String getEmail() {
        return this.email;
    }

    public void setEmail(String email) {
        this.email = email;
    }

    public String getPhone() {
        return this.phone;
    }

    public void setPhone(String phone) {
        this.phone = phone;
    }

    public String getLastname() {
        return this.lastname;
    }

    public void setLastname(String lastname) {
        this.lastname = lastname;
    }

}
```

*User.java*

```
package com.kadir.entity.authorize;

import com.kadir.entity.Employee;
import com.kadir.entity.Base;
import java.io.Serializable;
import javax.persistence.*;


import java.util.List;


/**
 * The persistent class for the USER database table.
 * 
 */
@Cacheable
@Entity
@Table(name="USER", schema="AUTHORIZE")
@NamedQuery(name="User.findAll", query="SELECT u FROM User u")
public class User extends Base implements Serializable {
    private static final long serialVersionUID = 1L;

    @OneToOne
    @JoinColumn(name="EMPLOYEEOBJID")
    private Employee employee;

    @Column(name="NAME")
    private String name;

    @Column(name="PASSWORD")
    private String password;

    public User() {
    }

    public Employee getEmployee() {
        return this.employee;
    }

    public void setEmployee(Employee employee) {
        this.employee = employee;
    }

    public String getName() {
        return this.name;
    }

    public void setName(String name) {
        this.name = name;
    }

    public String getPassword() {
        return this.password;
    }

    public void setPassword(String password) {
        this.password = password;
    }

}
```

Comment: Basically: you're making the common mistake of tying to translate SQL to JPQL, that doesn't work because they're absolutely not the same. The only way to approach the problem is to try to answer the question from the perspective of the model you have, and the model (the JPA entities) you are currently not showing. If Employee has a reverse mapping to User then this problem becomes infinitely simpler.

Comment: Employee does not have reverse mapping, there is just Employee object in User class. Is there any workaround for this situation or do I have to add reverse mapping? @Gimby

Comment: can i see both the entity class?

Comment: I have edited question with entity classes @Zia

Comment: try to use "IS EMPTY" instead of IS NULL in your query

Comment: @Zia I have tried it but no luck. It throws an error and says **The collection-valued path 'u.employee' must resolve to an association field.**

Comment: verify u.employee.objid = e.objid,is it right

Comment: You have the  u.employee.objid = e.objid contained within the where clause.  The u.employee cannot both have a objid AND be null, so it will not return results - this is not a 1:1 translation of the SQL.  EclipseLink supports using 'on' clauses, which is what you were using in your SQL.

Comment: @Zia yes u.employee.objid = e.objid is right because I have employeeId column in User table, it is not 1:1 relationship, it is 1:N relationship

Answer (score 5, accepted):

EclipseLink has support for the [ON clause](https://wiki.eclipse.org/EclipseLink/UserGuide/JPA/Basic_JPA_Development/Querying/JPQL#ON), so try using

```
"SELECT e FROM Employee e LEFT JOIN User u on u.employee = e WHERE u.employee IS NULL"
```

You can also use exist and a subquery:

```
"select e from Employee e where not exists (select 1 from User u where u.employee = e)"
```

Answer (score 1):

In my case, I'm using *Apache OpenJPA*.

Query should be something like this:

```
SELECT e FROM Employee e LEFT JOIN e.user u WHERE u.employeeId IS NULL
```

Answer (score 1):

I had similar error. I had conditional OneToOne relation. I fixed problem like that.

```
    @Query("SELECT e FROM Employee e LEFT OUTER JOIN User u ON  u = e.user " +
        "WHERE (u IS NULL OR e.condition = :conditionValue) ")
```

Comment: Employee doesn't have a 'user' to join over, if it did, there is no reason to specify the "ON u=e.user " clause - just use "LEFT JOIN e.user u where u IS NULL"